# How to consume a web service in java which returns the data in json format

Tags: json, java-6

This is the first time i am posting here ,so pardon me if i go wrong somewhere

My question here is : i would like to write a web service client in Java , that would consume json data from web service .

Any pointers to begin with or reference material on web would be of great help.

Platform i would like to use

Java 6 and would use gson to convert response from a service to java object.

Looking forward to your response.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of Spring WebServices and Flex JSON for marshalling/unmarshalling should probably be a fit for what you are looking for.

http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/